# Maven GWT plugin "failed with status 1" error

Tags: gwt, maven, compiler-errors, gwt-maven-plugin

Am trying to setup a GWT project using the gwt-maven-plugin but struggling to get this going. 
Have solve the issues around m2eclispe and lifecycle but am getting errors during build as Maven reports tasks failing with status 1. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
Command [[
/bin/sh -c /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
-Xmx512m 
-classpath 
/Users/jdoe/Documents/gwt-nesstarvester/src/main/java
:/Users/jdoe/Documents/gwt-nesstarvester/target/generated-sources/gwt
:/Users/jdoe/Documents/gwt-nesstarvester/src/main/resources
:/Users/jdoe/Documents/gwt-nesstarvester/target/gwt-nesstarvester-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
:/Users/jdoe/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar
:/Users/jdoe/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar
:/Users/jdoe/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
:/Users/jdoe/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
:/Users/jdoe/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.4.0/gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler 
-gen /Users/jdoe/Documents/gwt-nesstarvester/target/.generated 
-logLevel INFO 
-style OBF 
-war /Users/jdoe/Documents/gwt-nesstarvester/target/gwt-nesstarvester-1.0-SNAPSHOT 
-localWorkers 8 
org.openmetadata.gwt.nesstarvester.nesstarvester
]] 
failed with status 1 (org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile:default:prepare-package)
```

Comment: That command is the actual gwt compilation, as started from maven. You've only posted just enough to show what was started, not what happened - can you post more of the log, and perhaps the nestarvester.gwt.xml file?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  @ColinAlworth, where can I find a log that might show additional details?

Comment: @AndyD try running the maven command from the command line, and use the output from that command. If there isn't enough, the flags `-e` and  `-X` will provide even more detail, though a lot of it may be useless.

Comment: @AndyDennie, Guys I am having same error, can you please post the proper solution .

Comment: try running with the -e and -X flags as @ColinAlworth described.  This may show your problem (which is likely different than whatever mine was, which I no longer remember).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to build project with JDK 1.8 while having 1.7 in `pom.xml`. For some reason it's not back-compatible, so I had to change it to exact match:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```